# href link on displayfield value

Tags: javascript, url, extjs, extjs5

My app has a form for display data, with a displayfield.
This displayfield show web sites links and the value is a href link.

I am struggling to properly configure the href.

Can you help me, please?

```
{
  xtype: 'displayfield',
  fieldLabel: 'Web/URL',
  name: 'URL',
  autoEl: {
          tag: 'a',
          href: '',
       // href: '<a href="'+ this.value +'">'+ this.value +'</a>',
          target: '_blank'
  }
}
```

EDITED:

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/13u0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use 'click' listener event rather than using autoEl. You can add fieldCls config in order to style for the value.

```
items: [{ 
    xtype: 'displayfield', 
    fieldLabel: 'Displayfield',
    labelWidth: 100,
    name: 'link',
    value: 'http://stackoverflow.com',
    fieldCls: 'style-for-url', // class for url
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(view) {
            // Listener for onclick
            view.getEl().on('click', function() {
                window.open(view.value);
            })
        }
    }
}]
```

Comment: Thanks. Kohei. Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have to write the href attribute like this because you already specified that it is an "a" tag.

`href: this.value`

Comment: Thanks sagemoasta. Your suggestion does not work in my case (the link disappears).

Comment: I edted my post for insert a fiddle